# changing outlier rule from IQR to standard devations in geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers, standard-deviation

I know the default setting for `geom_boxplot()` is:

- Q3 + 1.5 * IQR
- Q1 - 1.5 * IQR

but I wanted to do 4 standard deviations from the mean:

- MEAN + 4 * SD
- MEAN - 4 * SD

Is this possible to do in ggplot2?  If not, what is the alternative?

I saw a post that asked about changing to different IQR, but I am specifically interested in changing to standard deviation.

Comment: maybe this could help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html

Comment: @MLavoie Thanks for the link. I just looked at it and couldn't find anything specific to changing outlier definitions to to SD. Did you have a specific section that you are referring to?

Comment: you can create a new stat..might be use in collaboration with stat_summary which can be included in your geom_boxplot()

Comment: the cloest I can see about this is in the documentation here 
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/geom_boxplot  . See the point about `coef` and perhaps even `outliers`

Comment: Extending on @InfiniteFlashChess' comment: use `geom_boxplot(..., stat = "identity")` and see `?geom_boxplot` for an example on how to change the default computations of  this function.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `stat = "identity"`, as mentioned in some of the comments, but the trick is to get the outliers into the data. Outliers need to be provided in a list column. Here's how you do it.

First, make up some data and draw a regular boxplot:

```
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(y = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100)+.5, rnorm(100)-1),
                x = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 100))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Now, calculate the stats manually and draw boxplot with alternative outlier definition. Note that I use mean +/- 2*SD so I get a few more outliers. It should be obvious how to change the code to +/- 4*SD.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% group_by(x) %>%
  summarize(middle = median(y),
            mean = mean(y),
            sd = sd(y),
            lower = quantile(y, probs = .25),
            upper = quantile(y, probs = .75),
            ymin = max(mean - 2*sd, min(y)),
            ymax = min(mean + 2*sd, max(y)),
            outliers = list(y[y<ymin | y > ymax])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, ymin = ymin, lower = lower,
             middle = middle, upper = upper, ymax = ymax,
             outliers = outliers)) + 
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Disclaimer: I've only tested this with the current development version of ggplot2, not sure whether it works with the version currently on CRAN.